# Symfony UniqueEntity Validation Message

Tags: php, symfony, validation, annotations, doctrine

i have a problem with the validation message when i use UniqueEntity.

Here is my code :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntityValidator;

/**
 * LaboratoryTestRequest
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="laboratory_test_request")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...\...Bundle\Repository\...Repository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"num"}, message="It looks like the num is already use !")
 */
class MyClass
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
 private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="num", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
 private $num;
```

The problem is, when i submit the form with a "num" that is already use, i don't have the "message" for the unique constraint. The form is submitted and i have this error :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata ... for the 
key 'Uniq_80B6DC...'
```

I don't understand why the message is not diplay in the form. Maybe i forgot something but i don't know what is missing because this is like the documentation.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

I found what was wrong. That was in the controller. None of validation constraint were working. The problem was this :

```
if($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isSubmitted())
{
...
}
```

In this code i don't verify if the form is valid, i thought isSubmitted verify this but it doesn't.
So, the solution i found for the moment is to add isValid() method like this :

```
if($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isSubmitted())
{
...
}
```

Like this, i have my error message in my form. 
There is just a little problem, the form is submit, then i come back to the form with error message like i want and nothing is save in database.

But if it's possible i want to have the error message directly after clic on the submit button.
So i let the topic open for the moment if someone want to share an other solution or upgrade this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `{{ form_errors(form) }}` in your twig view ?

Comment: Yes because i use {{ form_row(form.num)}}